# Use two indexes for the same table in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Product` model. 
I need to keep track of certain relations between two products, and to do this, I use a `Link` model having two attributes: `first_product_id` and `last_product_id`.

Should I just leave those two attributes as integers or should I add indexes pointing to the `Product` table ?
I wonder if it is a good practice to have two indexes for the same table and if it will increase queries performance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of queries you do and how many products are there.

Generally, it's a good idea to add index on fields you do queries on. The only downside is slower write time, but unless your your workload is extremely write-heavy, couple of extra indexes won't hurt